# Docstrings - one line vs multiple line

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

I'm adding some ([epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-fields.html)) documentation to a package I've written, and I'm coming across a lot of instances where I'm repeating myself a multitude of times.

```
def script_running(self, script):
    """Return if script is running

    @param script: Script to check whether running

    @return: B{True} if script is running, B{False} otherwise
    @rtype: C{bool}
    """
```

[PEP257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) says that:

> One-liners are for really obvious cases.

and also

> The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable).

---

Is there a general guideline or standard practice for when to draw the line between a one-liner (description) and full param/return fields?

Or when generating documentation should I include every applicable field for each function, regardless of how repetitive it seems?

Bonus question: Syntactically, what's the best way to describe the `script` param?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The general guideline you are looking for is right in [PEP257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) in what you quoted, maybe you just need to see it in action.

Your function is a good candidate for a one-line docstring (*"really obvious cases"*):

```
def script_running(self, script):
    """Check if the script is running."""
```

Usually if you say that a function is checking something it means that it's going to return `True` or `False`, but if you like you could be more specific:

```
def script_running(self, script):
    """Return True if the script is running, False otherwise."""
```

Once again all in one line.

I would probably also change the name of your function, because there's no need to emphasize on what the function works in its name (a script). A function name should be something sweet, short and meaningful about what the function does. Probably I'd go with:

```
def check_running(self, script):
    """Return True if the script is running, False otherwise."""
```

Sometimes the *function-name-imagination* is tired by all the coding, but you should try anyway to do your best.

For a multiline example, let me borrow a docstring from the [google guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments):

```
def fetch_bigtable_rows(big_table, keys, other_silly_variable=None):
    """Fetches rows from a Bigtable.

    Retrieves rows pertaining to the given keys from the Table instance
    represented by big_table.  Silly things may happen if
    other_silly_variable is not None.

    Args:
        big_table: An open Bigtable Table instance.
        keys: A sequence of strings representing the key of each table row
            to fetch.
        other_silly_variable: Another optional variable, that has a much
            longer name than the other args, and which does nothing.

    Returns:
        A dict mapping keys to the corresponding table row data
        fetched. Each row is represented as a tuple of strings. For
        example:

        {'Serak': ('Rigel VII', 'Preparer'),
         'Zim': ('Irk', 'Invader'),
         'Lrrr': ('Omicron Persei 8', 'Emperor')}

        If a key from the keys argument is missing from the dictionary,
        then that row was not found in the table.

    Raises:
        IOError: An error occurred accessing the bigtable.Table object.
    """
```

This could be one way to *"summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable)"*.

You might also be interested to look at this [example of pypi project](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example) that it's meant to be documented with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

My 2 cents: **Guidelines** are meant to give you an idea about what you should and shouldn't do, but they **are not strict rules** that you have to blindly follow. So at the end choose what you feel to be better.

---

I would like to clear something that is been said in another answer about hitting the ***Maximum Line Length*** with a docstring.

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) tells you to *"Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters"* even though at the end everyone does 80.

This are 80 characters:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this may be an edge case where a little long one sentence is all you really need:

```
def my_long_doc_function(arg1, arg2):
    """This docstring is long, it's a little looonger than the 80 characters
    limit.
    
    """
```

Is like a one-line docstring, meaning that is *for really obvious cases*, but on your editor (with the 80 character limit) is on multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is likely always some degree of repetition involved when adding extended syntax for docstrings, i.e. epydoc/sphinx markup.

I would also say this matter is subjective rahter than objective. Explicit is better than implicit, and would seem to follow the Zen of Python more.